# Define a constant to be used throughout an access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

Rather than specify a color for each element in a database, I would like to assign it to a variable, so that I can change all elements at once.  I know in android, it is in the res folder, something like

```
res folder: //Definition <resources> <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

Not sure how//where to apply in VBA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a global constant.

I suggest **creating a module* carrying global constants**:

```vb
' for use within the VBA
Public Const WhiteColor As Long = &HFFFFFF

' (optional) make the constant accessible for use in SQL queries
' they can consume only functions, not constants
Public Function GetWhiteColor() As Long
    GetWhiteColor = WhiteColor
End Function
```

If you added the function, you can use it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT GetWhiteColor() AS WhiteColor;
```

---

*) How to add and name new module:

1. Use menu **Insert** > **Module**.
2. Display **Properties** window (if not already visible) by menu **View** > **Properties Window** or by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>,
3. Select the module in the tree.
4. The first property in the Properties pane is the **(Name)** property. Change its value to what you want, e.g. `mConst`.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ColourIndex_1 As Long

ColourIndex_1 = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Range("A1").Interior.Color = ColourIndex_1
```